# Good practice to explicitly return the values of the function?

Tags: ruby, function, return-value

Would you prefer this:

```
def add(a, b)
  puts "ADDING #{a} + #{b}"
  return a + b
end
```

over this?

```
def add(a, b)
  puts "ADDING #{a} + #{b}"
  a + b
end
```

Comment: I would say that omitting the "return" statement is canonical but I'm interested to see if there are any good reasons for/against this convention...

Comment: @maerics: That's why I posted this question for discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's The Ruby Way™ to not include the `return` statement unless it's absolutely required.

I'm sure there's better examples, but here's a simple one.

```
def divide a, b
    return false if b == 0
    a/b
end
```

---

It's worth noting that Ruby provides means to optionally ignore a lot of syntax. `()` are optional unless you're nesting them. `{}` can be omitted in many cases too.

```
func(5, 5, {:hello => 'world'})
# is the same as
func 5, 5, hello: 'world'
```

You'll learn a lot more shortcuts as you go.

Comment: Fair enough. I came from a background previously of programming in C and C++, so omitting the `return` keyword looked ambiguous to me initially.

Comment: I agree it looks strange at first, but you really learn to love it. especially for lambda functions :)

Comment: Do you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function when it comes to lambda functions?

Comment: Yep. I provided in example in my answer, too.

Comment: The example `[1,2,3,4,5].reject { |n| return n > 3 }` wouldn't even work but raise a `LocalJumpError`. This is not a lambda, but a block argument to the method (which basically is a proc, not a lambda). There's 2 differences betweend procs and lambdas, argument checking and being able to return from them.

Comment: Would this be an example where the `return` keyword is necessary? https://gist.github.com/48fd2d86a658346ad4a8

Comment: @MichaelKohl my bad; I removed that example in the latest revision.

Comment: The functional and obvious way would be `if b==0 then false else a/b end`. If a method includes an early `return`, then `return` should be used at the end of that method as well. That's just common sense. Most coders do not follow that convention, but I think they should. I would omit `return` for short, simple expressions.

Comment: @stanigator no, you just have to provide the array yourself, i.e. your last line becomes `[jelly_beans, jars, crates]`

Answer (score 2):

The [Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) says to omit the explicit return

> Avoid return where not required.

```
# bad
def some_method(some_arr)
  return some_arr.size
end

# good
def some_method(some_arr)
  some_arr.size
end
```

Comment: Understood. It doesn't really explain why that's the case though (I have read the section in the link).

Comment: Haha.  Very true.  I think the accepted answer of `The Ruby Way` is about the only 'real' justificaiton.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this: http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

it explains how return works on procs, lambdas and blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the context. Usually, it is not necessary to put it explicitly: rubyists knows that the last expression is the returned one. However, on some rare occasions, the last expression is not easy to grasp, as in an interation or some obscure structure, so it might be good to put it. But usually, no not necessary.

EDIT:

And obviously, when you're trying to return an expression that is not the last of your method, you *have* to use return. As you would do with lazy-loaded accessors

Answer (score 0):

Pros for `return a + b`:

- readability
- less error prone

Cons:

- verbose

Comment: I find that sometimes if there are several places for last expressions that I forget to change one of them, when I did not use return to mark them.